# Tag wiki request for [deleted-room]

Tags: discussion, meta, tag-wiki

There is no tag wiki for [deleted-room](/questions/tagged/deleted-room).
Can someone create a tag wiki?
I don't have the reputation to do the wiki and I couldn't find a good wiki.

Comment: I suggested an edit.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Can you give the link for the edit?

Comment: Not sure what it should help you, but here @smiley: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63414

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you do not need reputation to create a tag wiki, just having an account suffices. It *will* end up in the Suggested Edits review queue, unless you have [20k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Second, a tag excerpt and tag wiki aren't always useful. If it's clear to which questions a tag applies there's no need for a tag excerpt; and I honestly doubt a detailed introduction (a tag wiki's purpose) to deleted rooms is necessary. If you need one, just browse the [deleted-room](/questions/tagged/deleted-room) questions.

For more information, see the [tag info editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4) or the [blog post about tag wikis](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/).

> #### What are Tag Wikis?
>
> The **usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt**, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.
>
> The **full tag wiki** is a detailed introduction to the topic, suitable as a destination for those curious about it:

Comment: The problem is, I couldn't come up with a good wiki.